# Replace line based on line number

Tags: unix, sed

I have not got any standard answer on how to use sed to replace a specific line with the line number.

May I know how to do that?

For example, I tried to replace line 45 using

```
sed -i '45s/*/T T F/' POSCAR
```

Not working...

Answer (score 2):

Add a dot:

Replace

```
sed -i '45s/*/T T F/' POSCAR
```

by

```
sed -i '45s/.*/T T F/' POSCAR
```

---

> `.`: match any character
>
> `*`: the preceding expression can match zero or more times

Comment: sed -i "s/$x $y $z T T F/$x $y $((z+0.01)) T T F/" test
-bash: 0.3688520225288983: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".3688520225288983")    May I know how to do arithmetic in sed using bash?

Comment: @LeiZhang that is an entirely different question

Comment: @LeiZhang: Please start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `perl` for this job too.

```
perl -i '$. == 45 && $_ = "T T F\n"' POSCAR
```

(Assuming you want to replace all of line 45)